# Remove leading strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am studying other people's code `df` and I face a similar problem to this where the data is joined whatsoever:

```
Names
--------
NurseJohn
SoldierJohn
TeacherJohn
DriverJohn
CEOJohn
```

How can I remove the words before John?

It can be removed like this but I don't understand how it was removed

```
df['Names'] = df['Names'].str.replace(".*(?=John)", "", regex=True)
```

Can someone explain to us what happened in `(".*(?=John)", "", regex=True)`? and with that, is there other way to do this straightforwardly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove everything before "John"? If so, all you need to do is simply assign "John" to each string because this is what you are essentially doing with your code. Wouldn't it make more sense, if "John" is removed and the rest remains?

Answer (score 1):

ya so...your using regex...[regex](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) is a tool ever lang ive worked with uses to search strings(text). Regex = Regular Expression. next you are using regex to exclude anything before "John", then **replace** with "" witch is an empty string.

so to read it from left to right:

1. call dataframe col 'Names'
2. for string in col, replace **ALL**(*) before "John" with empty string(""), using regex

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the regex pattern you should have used is:

```regex
.*(?=John$)
```

This pattern says to match all content, greedily, until hitting the content `John` at the very end of the `Names` column.  Note that it does not *consume* `John`, it only *asserts* that it follows, before stopping the match.

Your updated code:

```py
df["Names"] = df["Names"].str.replace(r'.*(?=John$)', '')
```